# How change a word to number ? First on 1 etc

Tags: javascript

I need to make a function that takes the word for example first, second, third and returns 1, 2, 3, etc.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this. The only solution I found was to convert 1 to 1st with `Intl.PluralRules`, please help and tips on how to do my problem. thank you

```
function(word){
   return number;
}

example:
first - 1
second - 2
```

Comment: @decpk This question is about ordinal numbers, not cardinal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just replace the text?

```
function(word){
   word = word.replace(/first/g, "1");
   word = word.replace(/second/g, "2");
   return word;
}
```